# Extract a word1 between two words A and B

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to extract a word1 between two words A and B but I wouldn't want to take spaces before and after word1. And i don't want take up a new word B occurrence.

Example:

```
library(stringr)
pattern <- "(?<=wA).*(?=wB)"
str1 <- "qzpdjpqz wA    Hello world !                   wB  edjifdjiq"
str2 <- "qzpdjpqz wA    Hello world !                   wB  wB"

str_match_all(str1, pattern)  
str_match_all(str2, pattern)

str11 <- "qzpdjpqz wA    word1                   wB  edjifdjiq\n 


qzpdjpqz wA                    word2                   wB 
wB\n

qzpdjpqz gregegt wA    word3                   wB  wB\n rsgeef vfsfeqz 

wA    word4 wB                 "
```

desired result ->  "Hello world !"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R option with `sub` removing whitespaces after `'wA'` and before `'wB'`.

```
str1 <- "qzpdjpqz wA    Hello world !                   wB  edjifdjiq"
str2 <- "qzpdjpqz wA    Hello world !                   wB  wB"

sub('.*wA\\s+(.*?)\\s+wB.*', '\\1', c(str1, str2)) 
#[1] "Hello world !" "Hello world !"
```

Comment: hello, thank for your help. I forgot to mention the context. I retrieve some text from a pdf using the pdftools package. The pdf is several pages, that's why I used the "str_match_all" function, the "sub" function only retrieves the first match of each page, not all the matches

Comment: Well, the same regex in `str_match_all` seems to work. Did you try that ? `sapply(str_match_all(c(str1, str2), '.*wA\\s+(.*?)\\s+wB.*'), \`[\`, 2)`

Comment: It works with the example I created but not with the content extracted from the pdf :(, it extract the whole row. I created another example.

Comment: I am not sure what am I missing. For your new example if I run the code `str_match_all(str11, '.*wA\\s+(.*?)\\s+wB.*')[[1]][, 2]` it returns `"word1" "word2" "word3" "word4"`. Isn't that what you need ?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of whitespaces is known, count them.

```
stringr::str_match_all(list(str1, str2), '(?<=wA\\s{4}).*(?=\\s{19}wB.+)')
# [[1]]
# [,1]           
# [1,] "Hello world !"
# 
# [[2]]
# [,1]           
# [1,] "Hello world !"
```

Otherwise try `regmatches(regexpr())`.

```
sapply(list(str1, str2), \(x) 
       trimws(regmatches(x, regexpr('(?<=wA).*(?=wB.+)', x, perl=TRUE))))
# [1] "Hello world !" "Hello world !"
```

Comment: hello, thank for your help, It works with the example I created but not with the real content extracted from the pdf  with the pdftools package. I created another example which will probably be closer to what I have, it's str11